# How to add a value to a dictionary that has a duplicate key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this problem where I would like to add a value to a dictionary but the key is duplicate.
I would like the key to to hold a list with multiple values

this is what I have tried

```
def storingPassword():
    username=("bob")#key,
    password=("PASSWROD1")#value 




    allpasswords={
        "jeff":"jeff 123 ",
        "bob" : "bob 123"
    }

    if username  not in allpasswords:
        allpasswords[username]=password
    else:
        allpasswords[username].append(password)
        

    return allpasswords
```

but i keep getting this error
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

I expect a output something like this;

```
        "jeff":"jeff 123 ",
        "bob" : ["bob 123","PASSWORD1"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the value in your `allpasswords`  dict is a string and you are trying to treat it like a list. Why are you trying to make your data structure complex with few values as list and few as string? I recommend to convert everything to *list* for a simpler logic.

Hence your code should be like this:

```
allpasswords={
    "jeff": ["jeff 123 "],
    "bob" : ["bob 123"]
}

allpasswords[username].append(password)
```

Instead of using `dict` object, you can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). It will let you define a dict with default value as `list`. So you don't need to even explicitly initialise value of new key as `list`. For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
my_dict['new_key'].append('new_value')

# dictionary will hold the value:
#     {'new_key': ['new_value']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Initiate your dictionary entry with a list instead of just a string.

```
allpasswords[username] = [password]   # List containing a single password
```

You will then be able to append to it.

(Having some entries contain a string while others contain a list of strings is best avoided - when it is time to look them up or print them, you would have to check each time whether it is a list or string.)

Comment: oh myyyy  now i see thanks